# Not getting Response from Cowin API using JAVA/Android

Tags: java, android, api, rest, android-studio

I am trying to fetch slots for covid19 vaccine using the below URL in my android app. this URL is working fine from browser and postman. but when my app is calling connection.getInputStream() it is never coming out of connection.getInputStream().
any idea what's wrong with the below code?

```
String COWIN_API_URL =
            "https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/sessions/public/calendarByPin?pincode=%s&date=%s";
URL url = new URL(String.format(COWIN_API_URL,pin , date));
            HttpURLConnection connection =(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setRequestProperty("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36");           
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```

**Update1:-** just found that this was due to the below error, actually Samsung Device will have this issue due to SBSetting.
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false

Comment: Are you getting any error message or nothing? And as you're calling a get api, have you tried using other libraries like Volley or retrofit?

Comment: @krish i am not geting error or responnse. debugger is waiting infinite after 'connection.getInputStream()'. Yes is am calling GET API. i have not tried other libraries.